# Pick subset from list at random and maintain equal number of picks overall in python

Tags: python, random, python-itertools

given a list of strings like so (in reality I have a much longer list but I'll keep it short for here):

```
items=['fish','headphones','wineglass','bowtie','cheese','hammer','socks']
```

I would like to pick a subset, say 3, of this list randomly so that items can only get picked once. This is easy enough using the following:

```
import itertools
import random
def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

items=['fish','headphones','wineglass','bowtie','cheese','hammer','socks']
randomPick=random_combination(items,3)
```

Next, to be a pain, I don't want to do this just once, but several times say 10 times. The final product would be 10 lists of randomly-only-picked-once items with the constraint that over those 10 lists items are presented an equal amount of times across lists. I'd like to avoid the "socks" to be picked up 10 times and the "hammer" only once for example.

This is the step that I'm stuck with, I simply don't know enough programming or enough about the available functions in python to perform such a thing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: if everything is picked only once then everything in the resulting lists will be picked the same number of times (i.e., once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok in the end I resorted in doing the following.
It is a more constrained implementation where I set the number of times I want to see an item repeat, for example over the 10 lists I want each items to be picked 5 times:

```
List = ['airplane',
            'fish',
            'watch',
            'balloon',
            'headphones',
            'wineglass',
            'bowtie',
            'guitar',
            'desk',
            'bottle',
            'glove'] #there is more in my final list but keeping it short here
numIters = 5
numItems = len(List)
finalList=[]
for curList in range(numIters):
    random.shuffle(List)
    finalList.append(List[0 : numItems/2]) #append first list
    finalList.append(List[numItems/2 : -1]) #append second list

return finalList
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code might help. It pops a random element until (a copy of) `iterable` is empty, then starts over from the entire list. The downside is every item is picked once before a single item can be picked a second time. However, as you can see from the output, the distribution of items ends up about equal.

```
import random

def equal_distribution_combinations(iterable, n, csize):
    """
    Yield 'n' lists of size 'csize' containing distinct random elements
    from 'iterable.' Elements of 'iterable' are approximately evenly
    distributed across all yielded combinations.
    """
    i_copy = list(iterable)

    if csize > len(i_copy):
        raise ValueError(
            "csize cannot exceed len(iterable), as elements could not distinct."
        )

    for i in range(n):
        comb = []
        for j in range(csize):
            if not i_copy:
                i_copy = list(iterable)

            randi = random.randint(0, len(i_copy) - 1)

            # If i_coppy was reinstantiated it would be possible to have
            # duplicate elements in comb without this check.
            while i_copy[randi] in comb:
                randi = random.randint(0, len(i_copy) - 1)
            comb.append(i_copy.pop(randi))

        yield comb
```

### Edit

Apologies for Python 3. The only change to the function for Python 2 should be `range` -> `xrange`.

### Edit 2 (answering comment question)

`equal_distribution_combinations` should result in an even distribution for any `n`, `csize`, and length of `iterable`, as long as `csize` does not exceed `len(iterable)` (as the combination elements could not be distinct).

Here's a test using the specific numbers in your comment:

```
items = range(30)
item_counts = {k: 0 for k in items}

for comb in equal_distribution_combinations(items, 10, 10):
    print(comb)
    for e in comb:
        item_counts[e] += 1

print('')
for k, v in item_counts.items():
    print('Item: {0}  Count: {1}'.format(k, v))
```

Output:

```
[19, 28, 3, 20, 2, 9, 0, 25, 27, 12]
[29, 5, 22, 10, 1, 8, 17, 21, 14, 4]
[16, 13, 26, 6, 23, 11, 15, 18, 7, 24]
[26, 14, 18, 20, 16, 0, 1, 11, 10, 2]
[27, 21, 28, 24, 25, 12, 13, 19, 22, 6]
[23, 3, 8, 4, 15, 5, 29, 9, 7, 17]
[11, 1, 8, 28, 3, 13, 7, 26, 16, 23]
[9, 29, 14, 15, 17, 21, 18, 24, 12, 10]
[19, 20, 0, 2, 25, 5, 22, 4, 27, 6]
[12, 13, 24, 28, 6, 7, 26, 17, 25, 23]

Item: 0  Count: 3
Item: 1  Count: 3
Item: 2  Count: 3
Item: 3  Count: 3
Item: 4  Count: 3
Item: 5  Count: 3
Item: 6  Count: 4
Item: 7  Count: 4
Item: 8  Count: 3
Item: 9  Count: 3
Item: 10  Count: 3
Item: 11  Count: 3
Item: 12  Count: 4
Item: 13  Count: 4
Item: 14  Count: 3
Item: 15  Count: 3
Item: 16  Count: 3
Item: 17  Count: 4
Item: 18  Count: 3
Item: 19  Count: 3
Item: 20  Count: 3
Item: 21  Count: 3
Item: 22  Count: 3
Item: 23  Count: 4
Item: 24  Count: 4
Item: 25  Count: 4
Item: 26  Count: 4
Item: 27  Count: 3
Item: 28  Count: 4
Item: 29  Count: 3
```

As can be seen, the items are evenly distributed.

Comment: Thanks! That seems pretty good. Just to check: Do you think that if I operated say on a list of 30 items and wanted to pick 10 (10times) it would lead to the same approximately similar distributions?

Comment: Oops there was a bug. A line in the function should have been `for i in range(n)` rather than the explicit `range(10)`

Comment: Improved the function a bit more. The answer has been updated.

Comment: @Narpar1217 when you, the author, look at the first and second result of the original answer (available in the edit history) then you know that in the third one you will have the word "bowtie". If the input list had had 9 items, the third "random" output would have been completely known. This is not meant as a criticism of your code, but as a perplexity about the soundness of the original request.

Comment: @gboffi can you explain this more? Would that be because the list given here is quite small or would that be different with a bigger list (30 items to be randomly and evenly picked into 10 lists)?

Comment: @Bastien No, it wouldn't be different, you know beforehand all the
elements in the third choice, with the randomness restricted to the
order of the outcomes.  A different question, e.g., "I have `n x m`
items and I want to choose randomly `n` sets/lists (is the order
important? no: sets; yes: lists) of `m` elements, without repetitions"
is meaningful, while the question as was posted has lead to the design of a dice that every 6 turns gives you all the possible values, a dice
that would give to its owner quite a bit of unfair advantage...

Comment: @gboffi I think I see what you mean now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would do something like this:

```
items = set(items)
res = []
for _ in xrange(10):
    r = random.sample(items, 3)
    res.append(r)
    items -= set(r)
```

all this does is grab 3 elements, store them, and then subtract them from the original list so they can't be selected again.

Comment: OK thats a simple one, but would that guarantee that items repeat an equal number of times across the 10 iterations?